# force g++ to zero initialize memory

Tags: c++, g++

I want to write some unit tests of a library I'm writing

I have a class which looks like this one :

```
class A
{
public:
    A(B* pB)
    // construction details, involves my library
    // but ultimately there is a new being done ,)

    B* m_pB;
};
```

I'd like to check that the pointer m_pB is actually initialized, so I did something along these lines :

```
A* p = // creation of this object involves my library
BOOST_REQUIRE( p->m_pB != NULL );
```

but it happens g++ does not zero-initialize the memory, so the value of `p->m_pB` is just plain random. Is there a way to force g++ to zero initialize this memory for me when I `new` the object?

I believe Visual Studio does something similar with specific codes dependeing on where the memory is allocated.

edit: I can think of 2 backup solutions right now: using a smart pointer, or writing a new operator ...

Comment: Why don't you want to initialize m_pB to zero in the class constructor?

Comment: Er, what do you want to check, exactly? Your ctor should take care of all member initialisation — you want zero, put zero in there.

Comment: Do you want the pointer to default to something or the memory the pointer points to? It's not clear from your question ...

Comment: what do you want zero initialized? the pointer m_pB, or the object that the pointer points to? if its the pointer, how can it be zero initialized if it is a required parameter of the constructor? in this design, it is your responsibility to ensure that the pointer is NULL or not NULL...

Comment: See here: [new and parentheses][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new

It may help

Comment: the pointer itself. It could be forgotten in the constructor for instance, but more specifically, the library does dependency injection and B is a dependency, and a bug could result in m_b not being initialized

Comment: so implement the default constructor: "A() : m_pB(NULL) {}"

Comment: If everything fails (which I doubt will happen) and all you want to check is if the pointer is initialized I guess you could try the GNU debugger (gdb).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, but I'd like a less invasive technique, as the classes are part of the test, and their constructor is right in the midle of the subject which is dependency injection.

I was just hopping for something similar to visual studio which sets the memory to some specific value in debug mode (I think?), through an option of g++ or something alike.

some answers/comments basically fall back to saying "don't test it, just don't make the mistake"

Finally, I've overloaded the new operator and added a call to `memset(ptr, 0, size);`
and I get my `critical check p->m_pB != __null failed`, it works fine.

you all get a +1 anyway, especially DeadMg for the interesting solution

Comment: That only works for dynamically allocated objects, because `operator new` won't be called if you put an `A` on the stack.

Comment: isn't the point of unit tests to find problems with your code? I'd say you just found your first one. the solution isnt to overload the new operator, but to simply fix your code!!!! I suggest you look up "C++ initializer list", you need to learn what these are going forward.

Comment: @Fred my objects are all dynamically allocated  @J T thank you but I know how to fix this 'problem' I don't need your help, I also know what initializer lists are. All I asked was "Is there a way to force g++ to zero initialize this memory for me when I new the object?"

Comment: @foke: the answer is 'yes' to your question, and its done by using a constructor initializer list.

Answer (score 9):

Simply implement the default constructor. This guarantees that without passing an argument, the pointer is initialized to NULL.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(B* pB)
    // construction details, involves my library
    // but ultimately there is a new being done ,)

    A() : m_pB(NULL) {}

    B* m_pB;
};
```

Or as Fritschy points out:

```
A() : m_pB() {}
```

Comment: It's even *enough* to default-initialize the member.

Answer (score 5):

Use an always-initializing class.

```
template<typename T> class always_initialized {
    T t;
public:
    operator T&() { return t; }
    operator const T&() const { return t; }
    always_initialized() : t() {}
    always_initialized(const T& ref) : t(ref) {}
};
```

Edit: I see that most people didn't understand what this actually does. If you just set the pointer to NULL, then you have to do that separately in every constructor, and then you have to do that again for every variable, and it's also not generic for other POD things like POD structs. `always_initialized` is more maintainable, as you're not repeating yourself, more concise, and more generic, as it's good for any POD type or even non-POD type.

Comment: +1 Nice hack but don't you also need a conversion constructor and assignment operator?

Comment: @dark_charlie: Sure, I could waste my life providing them, or the OP could just get the hint and write them himself. And that's not a hack at all.

Comment: umm, i dont think this actually helps the OP with regards to their problem

Comment: @Thomas: Mind fart- fixed. @J T: I think that it will quite clearly always set the pointer to 0. If you don't get how that will solve the OP's problem, perhaps you should read the question again. More carefully this time.

Comment: @DeadMG: Perhaps I am just ignorant, but why would t() initialized POD types if A() does not (which is the problem that the OP is having)?

Comment: @DeadMG: let's say we wrote always_initialized<A> my_obj; why is m_pB is initialized as NULL here? what is the difference between A my_obj; and former? as far as i can see former calls t() (which is A()) in turn. so how?

Comment: You _do_ lose the implicit conversions, though. `int->float` is implicit, `always_initialized<int> -> float` is user-defined. Since you can't have two user-defined conversions in a conversion sequence, this does matter.

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider making `m_pB` private and always initializing it in your constructors? By using encapsulation to enforce your class invariants you don't even *need* to do the kinds of checks you're implementing here.